# CodeIgniter Active Record: Load One Row at a Time

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, lazy-loading

The normal `result()` method described in the documentation appears to load all records immediately.  My application needs to load about 30,000 rows, and one at a time, submit them to a third-party search index API.  Obviously loading everything into memory at once doesn't work well (errors out because of too much memory).

So my question is, how can I achieve the effect of the conventional MySQLi API method, in which you load one row at a time in a loop?

Comment: I don't think you can. Did you try loading multiple queries with `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`, maybe load 1000~ records a time.

Comment: Work back from what you can reasonably pass to the search api, whether thats 10 or 100 or 1000, etc. Put something in place in case the group submission fails, and you have to resubmit to the search api.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is something you can do.

```
while ($row = $result->_fetch_object()) {
  $data = array(
    'id'         => $row->id
    'some_value' => $row->some_field_name
  );
  // send row data to whatever api
  $this->send_data_to_api($data);
}
```

This will get one row at the time. Check the CodeIgniter source code, and you will see that they will do this when you execute the result() method.

Comment: Thank you, @elvispt, even though this depends on an internal interface, it seems to be the only option.

Comment: Thank you! Previously I've just used the regular old mysql functions when I've had to deal with datasets larger than PHP could hold in memory. This is waaaaay better.

Comment: I'm surprised this hasn't been voted higher in 2 years. This is a fantastic way of saving memory. Some of my queries would not be possible without this :)

Answer (score 4):

For those who want to save memory on large result-set:

Since **CodeIgniter 3.0.0**,
There is a `unbuffered_row` function,

> All the methods above will load the whole result into memory (prefetching). Use unbuffered_row() for processing large result sets.

> This method returns a single result row without prefetching the whole result in memory as row() does. If your query has more than one row, it returns the current row and moves the internal data pointer ahead.

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

while ($row = $query->unbuffered_row())
{
    echo $row->title;
    echo $row->name;
    echo $row->body;
}
```

> You can optionally pass ‘object’ (default) or ‘array’ in order to specify the returned value’s type:

```
$query->unbuffered_row();               // object
$query->unbuffered_row('object');       // object
$query->unbuffered_row('array');        // associative array
```

Official Document: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#id2

Comment: Hi @Tiger, I know this is an old thread, but may I ask a question? Should I implement the unbuffered_rows on my controller? If not, then probably it should be on the model. But if that is the case, how can I pass the data to my controller, one at a time? Please bear with me, I am still learning CodeIgniter. I am curious how to speed up my data retrieval. Thank you....

Comment: @DanAngeloAlcanar I have the same question after 3 years

Answer (score 0):

Well, the thing is that `result()` gives away the entire reply of the query. `row()` simply fetches the first case and dumps the rest. However the query can still fetched 30 000 rows regardles of which function you use.

One design that would fit your cause would be:

```
$offset = (int)@$_GET['offset'];

$query = $this-db->query("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT ?, 1", array($offset));
$row = $query->row();

if ($row) {

    /* Run api with values */

    redirect(current_url().'?offset'.($offset + 1));

}
```

This would take one row, send it to api, update the page and use the next row. It will alos prevent the page from having a timeout. However it would most likely take a while with 30 000 records and refreshes, so you may wanna adjust your `LIMIT ?, 1` to a higher number than `1` and go `result()` and `foreach()` multiple apis per pageload.

Comment: Unfortunately an HTTP redirect would not work in this case, as it's being called through the command line.  It doesn't seem like a super-practical solution... I guess I might have to use the database adapter directly?

Comment: You could call it each minute and check em of through an extra mysql column so it will `WHERE api = 'FALSE'` for you instead.

Answer (score -1):

Well, there'se the **[row()](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)** method, which returns just one row as an object, or the **row_array()** method, which does the same but returns an array (of course).

So you could do something like

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM yourtable";
$resultSet = $this->db->query($sql);
$total = $resultSet->num_rows();

for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++) {
  $row = $resultSet->row_array($i);
}
```

This fetches in a loop each row from the whole result set.
Which is about the same as fetching everyting and looping over the `$this->db->query($sql)->result()` method calls I believe.

If you want a row at a time either you make 30.000 calls, or you select all the results and fetch them one at a time or you fetch all and walk over the array. I can't see any way out now.

Comment: But the whole set can't be in memory at any given time.  I want to select a row, push it off to the API, and dispose of that data, and repeat.